# UglifyJS seems to interfere with React dist used in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, uglifyjs, create-react-app

These are the bits of my Webpack configuration that seem to be relevant to my issue:

```
new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['NODE_ENV']),

// Minify the code.
new UglifyJSPlugin({
  compress: {
    dead_code: true,
    drop_debugger: true,
    warnings: false
  },
  output: {
    comments: false
  }
}),
```

I am using an ejected version of the CRA config that looks pretty much the same and gets its environment vars from `build.js` - note that I kept this condition

```
if (env['process.env'].NODE_ENV !== '"production"') {
  throw new Error('Production builds must have NODE_ENV=production.');
}
```

in my production webpack config, so I doubt the problem is that I am not passing my environmental variable correctly.

Interestingly enough, I have been getting this React error:

`Warning: It looks like you're using a minified copy of the development build of React.`

If I remove the minification related code (the entire UglifyJSPlugin block) the resulting bundle is obviously bigger, but the React warning is gone. Any idea on what could be causing this?

---

EDIT: even when I explicitly set my `NODE_ENV` to `production` with webpack-define-plugin this was `'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')` I still get this error with Uglify.

Comment: You need to swap the unminified ReactJS code with the official minified ReactJS version

Comment: The react warning goes away on removing uglifyjs because the minifier is running on the 'development build' of react instead of the prod build. Use the uglifyjs build only while building for production (NODE_ENV==='production')

Comment: How would using an already minified version of React solve this? 
Currently I am installing React with yarn and I have defined it this way in the dependencies of my application: "react": "^15.4.1"

Comment: @kumar_harsh I would expect my configuration to throw if I weren't, because I kept the condition mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the React bundle is coming from a badly bundled library I am using in my application: enabling source map in my uglify options allowed me to find this out easily.